# How can I switch On / Off LED Camera Flash on Windows 8 tablets (such as ATIV Smart PC)

Tags: windows, flash, camera, led

I can't find a code to control windows 8 tablets camera flash. Can anyone help me get it?

Comment: In what language & environment?

Comment: @SLaks C++ ,, using Visual Studio for windows 8

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151590(v=vs.85).aspx

:D hopefully this helps you get to your solution